# fetching and splitting an address from MongoDB to only return the host ID

Tags: python, mongodb, shell

I am trying to convert a shell script to python to access the MongoDB. 
I have the code :

```
primport = [] 
primport = call('/opt/mongodb/bin/mongo localhost27017 --eval "printjson(rs.isMaster())" | grep "primary"', shell = True)
```

and when I'm trying to print primport, the whole value gets printed :

```
 `"primary" : "1404Base:27017"`,
```

. which is not what i want. I want only the host ID 27017. I tried using python split function but it says int object has no attribute split. I need only the ID as I have to pass it as an argument in the upcoming code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `call` is from the `subprocess` module, `call` returns the shell return code of the command, not the STDOUT. You want to get `STDOUT` of the command, and for that you should use `subprocess.check_output`.

Try using:

```
primport = subprocess.check_output('/opt/mongodb/bin/mongo localhost27017 --eval "printjson(rs.isMaster())" | grep "primary" | cut -d ":" -f 2,3', shell = True)
```

**EDIT:**
Also, added a `cut` to your system call so you don't have to do any cleaning in Python.

Comment: the subprocess.checkoutput works, and when I'm trying to print, it prints the whole value (which is fine). The split method is also returning the same output. 
Technically, I have "primary" : "1404Base:27017", and though i'm trying to split it using delimiter : , it gives the same thing.

Comment: primport.strip("0123456789=,")
i have tried the strip method too, to strip all the digits and , from the output, but it still returns the whole damn thing again!

Comment: You can add `| cut -d ":" -f 2,3` at the end of your system call and you won't have to do the strip or split in python. So your command will be `'/opt/mongodb/bin/mongo localhost27017 --eval "printjson(rs.isMaster())" | grep "primary" | cut -d ":" -f 2,3'`

Comment: Also, note that the `check_output` returns bytestring as output. So, you should decode it to whatever encoding you are using with `decode`.

Comment: tried that too, it returns "1404Base:27017", !! 
when  I try I cut -f1 -d, |cut -f3 -d :' it returns me 27017". I have to get rid of the quote at the end!

Comment: it worked when I used another |grep '[0-9]{1,}' !! to return 27017. You reply was helpful. @munircontractor